# Would Google Translate do a good job for translating my software?

Tags: localization, translation, globalization

Just wondering how users translate their software, I've just finished making my software able to use different language but I'm not sure that Google translate is accurate enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; I wouldn't recommend it.

Machine translators will not handle short domain-specific strings very well.

Your UI is likely to have non-standard words or usages that the translator will choke on or mistranslate.

Also, machine translations tend to look very unprofessional.

Comment: Thanks, I'll find a translator then

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Google Translate would be sufficient, I would recommend to get a collaborator that knows your language and the language that you want to translate to.

Answer (score 0):

Google translate might work for lists of words but will make a mess of sentences and make your software look really bad.  Better to hire or talk nicely to a native speaker to get your sentences translated.